# Which Files Should Be Read-Only for TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, permissions

I was upgrading from VS 2008 to VS 2010. When I was getting errors in the auto-upgrade saying that files could not be opened, I made (what a I believe to be) a mistake and just went to Explorer and un-checked "read-only" for the containing folders and didn't check the files out. I now want to go through and set those files to "read-only" again, so I don't break stuff. Does anyone know which files are meant to be read-only and which ones, if any, are not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files which are not checked out should be read-only. Once a file is checked out, it becomes writable.

Comment: If I just set everything to read-only, when I rebuild, I get a bunch of access denied warnings and errors (mostly when it's trying to delete old items). However, if I set everything to not read-only, then do a clean, then (again) set everything to read-only, it rebuilds fine.

Comment: Exactly which files do you get errors about? Nothing in bin or obj should be in source control - it should all be writeable.

Comment: I was getting errors about files in bin and obj... It's all better now though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution is the following:

- Mark all files read-write
- In Visual Studio Clean the solution to remove all not versioned files
- Mark all files read-only
- Run "tfpt online" or "tf folderdiff" to find all modified files and check them out
- check in files checked out in previous step
- run build to make sure everything is fine